# China: defined benefit and defined contribution pensions

Tags: data-request, saving, china

DB means defined benefit pension plan.  DC means defined contribution pension plan. What is the DB and DC mix for employees of private employers in China?  Is the trend away from DB and towards DC?  Do younger companies typically not offer DB?  Do employers typically allow the employee to choose?